# Shopify: Pass a Search Query String to Landing Page Search Function?

Tags: shopify, liquid, google-ads-api

I'm currently managing a Google AdWords account for a cookie cutter company and have dreamed up an idea to get the most efficient conversions out of our campaign landing pages, but it will take some technical know-how, which I don't currently have an over abundance of.

Here's my idea:

In AdWords, you can create landing pages for each ad that you have, which is supposed to be the most relevant page for the search term that triggered the ad. This is great, unless you have a few thousand products that you're trying to sell. I did a lot of research and learned that you can find out the user's exact search term by just looking at the URL. That's simple enough, but I want to dynamically/automatically do this, which I believe is described at this link:

http://www.quickr.org/PHP_function_to_get_search_engine_referral_keywords

For example, an AdWord link would look like this:

http://www.google.com/aclk? ... &q=mason+jar+cookie+cutter

and I would want the term "mason jar cookie cutter" pushed to the site's search function, which would take that string and automatically search for that term on page load or something. If this process takes more than a few seconds to do, I'd ideally like to have some sort of splash/load screen, much like the ones that appear when a travel site is searching or loading your query. I would want this because it would reduce people from bouncing off the site, because it looks like some process is taking place.

This would, in theory, effectively give every customer a unique and relevant landing page that already has the search results of their desired term, which was taken from their original google search.

I'm not familiar with the Shopify platform and what languages does or not support, other than its Liquid language. I tried searching, but couldn't find a definitive answer

This is my first question on this site, and it seems like you guys have an incredible community of smart and gifted users. I'd appreciate any and all input on the matter, as well as any suggestions to improve my question.

Thank you!

Comment: You can certainly do this.  Do you have any code that you have tried?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Hi user2121180.**

i found your post, because i searched for: *"build adwords landing pages with query string"*

Now this generates a SERPS URL in the following Format:

https: //www.google.com /search?num=100&client=firefox-a&hs=DhQ&rls=org.mozilla%3Ade%3Aofficial&q=build+adwords+landing+pages+with+query+string&oq=build+adwords+landing+pages+with+query+string&gs_l=serp.3...0.0.0.202035.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c..11.serp.LyoL9Ab_xz8

Once I click on a Adwords button, -and get i got back (history(-1)) in my browser, i can see the following link, if i hover over the same ad again. So basically this is the link, that gets called once i click the ad....

http: //www.google.com /aclk?sa=l&ai=CqAWQsGx_UYT5IeWS0wWUtoD4C-_r0v4Cp52RkVG34uzdBAgAEAIgtlQoA1DH74CFB2CV-vCBjAegAdmK6OMDyAEBqQITlu9gnbWSPqoEKE_QkMDqa8IZvHQjiFZUuCqr5yMmiWaTIsfVTTDRYZp-E8Y5bN5NhTOABZBOgAeP9Zcc&sig=AOD64_023WkGcg-Uze3A72XOc-cNmor6nA&ved=0CDcQ0Qw&adurl=http: //lp1.pagewiz.com/Zielseiten%3Fcmp%3Dggl282812%26t%3D301%26cmpn%3Dgermany&rct=j&q=build+adwords+landing+pages+with+query+string

or alternativly also this link:

http: //www.google.com /aclk?sa=l&ai=CUOQGxm1_UcqoEOWS0wWUtoD4C9ep8HeVq4CbNMeuu7oBEAIoCFCF7Ivo-f___*8BYJX68IGMB6AB-bT*_gPIAQGpAggSgG2w-LU-qgQoT9BTixgE7SyYVxCD9P4-g3Jf-EyWFbWU69IRBNoqGkKhGdWJSx4siIAH78qAAQ&num=5&sig=AOD64_0O6ikX0qnkP6MFTu5zakOWARSaWg&ved=0CNoHENEM&adurl=http: //www.gandke.de/google-adwords-optimieren.html&rct=j&q=build+adwords+landing+pages+with+query+string

To boil it down it's

http: //www.google.com /aclk?sa=l&q=build+adwords+landing+pages+with+query+string

meaning that a simple PHP

```
if isset ($_GET['q']) {
  $myvar = $_GET['q'];
}
```

OR

```
if isset ($_POST['q']) {
  $myvar = $_POST['q'];
}
```

would do the job. you coould then use this $myvar and do lot's of funny things: 
In your header od something like

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo($myvar); ?> - YOUR COMPANY NAME</title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo($myvar); ?>, some more descriptive text" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo($myvar); ?>, other,keywords,and,more" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Are you looking for <?php echo($myvar); ?>?</h1>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum dolor etc otherwise do dang dung peng pong. Lorem Ipsum dolor etc otherwise do dang dung peng pong. Lorem Ipsum dolor etc otherwise do dang dung peng pong. Lorem Ipsum dolor etc otherwise do dang dung peng pong. 
</p>
<h3>Your solution for <?php echo($myvar); ?>?</h3>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum dolor etc otherwise do dang dung peng pong. etc...
</p>
</body>
</html>
```